# Compass compiles file and labels as "identical", but should not have compiled the file at all

Tags: compilation, sass, compass-sass

I'm using SASS 3.3.8 and Compass 1.0.0.alpha.19.

In the interest of shortening SASS compile times in my project, I have split my stylesheets, @import-ing shared mixins, variables, and placeholder selectors. My project file structure looks like this:

```
scss/
    library/
    _library.scss
    _section_a_widgets.scss
    _section_b_widgets.scss
    section_b.scss
    section_a.scss
```

In section_a.scss, I have:

```
@import "library";
@import "section_a_widgets";
```

In section_b.scss, I have:

```
@import "library";
@import "section_b_widgets";
```

This way, when I am working on, e.g., section_a_widgets.scss, I should only have to wait for section_a.scss to compile.

For some reason when I save section_a_widgets.scss, my Compass task indicates that section_a.scss has been "overwritten" (this makes sense), but also indicates that section_b.scss is "identical". This does not make sense to me, as nothing in section_a_widgets.scss is being included in sction_b.scss, and it defeats the purpose of splitting my stylesheets because Compass needs nearly as much time to reach the conclusion that the file was identical, as it does to overwrite the file with new changes.

Does anyone have insight into where I could have gone wrong in my setup? My goal is to reach a point where when I save section_a_widgets.scss, section_a.scss would be "overwritten", but section_b.scss would be "unchanged" (indicating Compass did not bother to try to compile it).

Thanks!

Comment: We will need more info, what compass version are you using ? Are you doing a compass compile or compass watch ? Can you also show your config.rb file ? Im trying to reproduce your issue, but in my environment, everything work as expected, if I make a change on section_a_widgets.scss, it only overwrite section_a.css and nothing related to section_b...

Comment: @avcajaraville Thanks so much for looking into this. I'm using SASS 3.3.8 and Compass 1.0.0.alpha.19. I'm using grunt-contrib-compass so my configuration is split between my gruntfile and config.rb - http_images_path = '../'
http_generated_images_path = '../', sassDir: '<%= paths.web %>/scss/',
cssDir: '<%= paths.web %>/style/', imagesDir: '<%= paths.web %>/'

Comment: @avcajaraville Also, when you make a change to section_a_widgets, does your compass task indicate that section_b.scss was "identical" or "unchanged"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, due to the information gathered on the comments, the main issue here is that grunt-contrib-compass is executing compass through compass compile command and not through compass watch.

This means, that every time the task is executed, it will go through all your assets and process them. If they are identical, nothing will happen, but as you said, you will loose time analyzing them.

What you are looking for is compass watch, which will be executed every time a file change and only on the files that had been changed. This is useful to have as a task that is working on the background, and if you have this task active, you will get your desired results.

Notice that this will work during your work time, I mean, you have this task running, you modify your files and only the affected ones will be recompiled, and the other ones, ignored.

You have to read the documents in order to set up this environment. On their official repository page, there are some examples you can check out: [check here.](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass#watch)

Hope this helps and put you on the good track !

Comment: I see! Thanks so much - I didn't know that compass compile worked that way. I've also just learned that grunt-contrib-compass has a "watch" boolean option, to override the default behavior of using "compile". Thanks again!